# How do I forcibly kill a locked screen session?

Tags: command-line, passwords, gnu-screen

I have an old `screen` session on a server that seems to be password-protected. The problem is, I don't recall setting a password on it, and I have no idea what the password could be. Any terminal window that may have had it attached is long gone. How do I forcibly remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You can kill any programs you want want with the `kill` command.
( Well, not any. Any program you started or all programs if you are root. )

Use `ps` to see what you are running. Note the PID (process Id) of the program you want to stop, Then type `kill -1 12345` (where 12345 is the PID of the process you want to stop).

This kill signal the program with a SIGHUP (Losely translated: The other side has hung up the modem. Please save any data you have left and gracefully terminate).

If that does not work use either `kill -15` (terminate now) or the rude `kill -9` (OS: please nuke this from orbit).

If you used one of the less subtle methods then you probably want to manually clean up afterwards. See `screen -wipe` and `screen -list`.

Comment: I'm not new to Linux—I know about signaling processes. :) I was looking for a more specific solution, as `screen` seems to be more complex than the everyday processes you start from a shell and just `^C` to kill. Also, the copy of `screen` in question is setuid root (some are, and it's required for multiuser mode), so others might not be able to simply `kill` the process.

Comment: With all due respect, while your answer was not technically helpful, it did inspire me to try a few signals, and I found that sending the background `SCREEN` process a `SIGTERM` _appears_ to cause it to exit gracefully. The socket was removed from `/var/run/screen/S-blackl`, the session no longer appeared in `screen -ls`, and attempts to reattach to it returned a no-matching-session error. When I used this with a test session open in another window, the usual `[screen is terminating]` appeared and the terminal returned to a normal prompt. It also worked for the locked session.

Comment: I had no idea from your post that you knew. I guess I did too much partial helldesk work in the past. (The default assumption for me is that a user is utterly clueless). Not a healthy state of mind.

Comment: I understand…in contexts like these, it is often hard to tell how much a given user knows, and whether they would understand something simple (“send the `SCREEN` process a `SIGTERM`”) or whether you would have to explain it more. :) In any case, one solution to this seems to be `SIGTERM`ing the background process (the one that shows up in `ps` with `SCREEN` in all caps and the arguments used to create the session). This only works, however, if the user owns the process (i.e. `screen` is not setuid root) or if they can use `sudo kill` or log in as root.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem when I first tried the lock screen.

You can solve this problem by doing:

```
kill [session # you want to kill]
```

or

```
 sudo kill [session # you want to kill]
```

For example:

```
neal@Master:~$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        2782.pts-0.Master       (廿十七年二月八日 十九時廿六分十九秒)   (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-neal.
```

which is locked and I forgot the passwd. So I run the command below to kill this detached screen.

```
kill 2782
```

Hope this could solve your problem!